# MySQL Normalization vs Denormalization

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization, denormalization

I'm creating an online marketplace for buyers and sellers. One of the questions for sellers is "Do you accept product returns?" If so, the second question is "Who pays for the returned item: the buyer or the seller?"

I always go for normalized designs usually. So I typically would design the database like this with an **items** table and a **return_payers** table and use a join:

```
items
id  |  title |  description |  price    | returns_accepted | 
------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |  blah  |   blah blah  |   80.00   |     0  // No
 2  |  blah  |   blah blah  |  120.00   |     1  // Yes
 3  |  blah  |   blah blah  |   40.00   |     1  
 4  |  blah  |   blah blah  |   60.00   |     0 

return_payers
id |  item_id  | payer
--------------------------------
 1 |    2      |   1  //Buyer
 2 |    3      |   2  //Seller
```

But because it's just one extra bit of information I'm thinking I could just append an extra column to the products like so, reducing the need for a join and possibly speeding read time:

```
products
id  |  title |  description |  price    | returns_accepted | returns_payer
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |  blah  |   blah blah  |   80.00   |     0            |      NULL
 2  |  blah  |   blah blah  |  120.00   |     1            |         1
 3  |  blah  |   blah blah  |   40.00   |     1            |         2 
 4  |  blah  |   blah blah  |   60.00   |     0            |      NULL
```

The reason I'm wondering is because I don't just have one example like this but the products have loads of little questions like this such as does it have a warranty? yes/no and if so how long etc. If I have say 20 of these little questions, the normalized design would require 20 more tables with 20 joins, the denormalized design would have one table, no joins but a lot of NULL values.

Because it's an online marketplace, the tables will be read far more than they are updated.

Advice welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Neither of these scenarios is any more or less normalized than the other in any meaningful way.  Technically, I guess you could say the distinction is there between 5NF and 6NF but that's hardly worth the trouble.  Who pays for returns is an attribute of the item, and seems perfectly valid as an attribute in the items table.  There's nothing wrong with nulls.

Comment: Why not 0, 1, or 2 (unaccepted, buyer, seller)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The second design is clearly a denormalization of the first in a certain reasonable idiomatic SQL sense (involving left joining instead of inner joining). Although since there's presumably one payer per return it is a denormalization of an *unnecessary* normalization. Which maybe is what you are referring to.

Comment: Hi. An answer to your question involves explaining 1. relational normalization 2. SQL analogues 3. SQL denormalization & 4. SQL optimization. Find out about them. This question is too broad & not researched. Also it is a faq. Also it is not possible for others to trade off your read speed vs space taken unless *you* give costs & benefits for *your* situation.

Comment: @philipxy yes, that's what I was thinking when I said "in a meaningful way."  It's not a necessary further normalization, as there is no apparent benefit... and the denormalized form doesn't appear to introduce any risk of anomalies.  You are of course correct, technically.

Answer (score 0):

This is a philosophical question, as there are going to be many 2c opinions and "in my experience" ideas out there.  So, in that world, here's one:

denormalizing a table is perfectly normal, as long as your data processes are clearly defined.  Your database needs to be designed with two thoughts in mind: first, it needs to quickly support your application; and second, it must be future-proofed as much as possible to prevent bottlenecks as your data holdings and application grows.

An idea for you is to build out your normalized data model, so you can perform business intelligence against it, then have an automatic ETL (data transfer) where you can denormalize your data into a separate aggregation table, hyper-indexed, to support your operations.  Because you are doing it this way, you can now leverage your data for future sales, plus you'll have a specific table support your operations.

of note, in either way, if you plan on performing any sort of analysis on your data, having your normalized database (data warehouse) on a different server then your denormalized (operations data base) will prevent slowdowns on your web server while you are doing your analytics.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not a philosophical decision it is an engineering decision. Which begs a technical analysis based on normalization & a cost-benefit tradeoff.

Comment: I agree.  I meant philosophical because there can be multiple ways in solving this.  And even Kimball and Inman couldn't agree on some points. :).  I like the question tho.